# Annotate query by existance in M2M

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Schema: tables A and B with M2M between them.

I have some queryset QS0 of A objects and one exact instance of B object.

How to annotate QS0 with True if B is connected with A through M2M and False if it is not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the example models below

```py
from django.db import models

class ModelA(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class ModelB(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    a_objects = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA, related_name='b_objects')
```

You should in theory be able to annotate a queryset of `ModelA` objects on whether they are each linked to a `ModelB` object in the following way.

```py
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value

b_object = ModelB.objects.get(id=some_id)

QS0 = ModelA.objects.annotate(is_linked_to_b=Case(When(b_objects__id=b_object, then=Value(True)), default=Value(False), output_field=BooleanField())

# QSO[some_index].is_linked_to_b should return either True or False.
```